Visual studio code is showing errors, but everything is working fine. How to resolve this issue?

I'm currently working on an Angular project, and I've noticed that Visual Studio Code is displaying false errors in several components, such as modules.ts, where I've imported certain components (as shown in the image). However, everything is functioning correctly. How can I resolve this issue?
It all happened after update.
Even after fresh cloning repository, I am facing similar issues.

Did you restart VS Code? First thing to try - it sometimes gets confused about what's installed.

Yes i have done that as well.

Here's a general checklist for this kind of problem. If this doesn't resolve your errors, please share more info about your setup, such as the component where this template is inside of and the module that the component is declared in!~

If you're freshly cloning a repo, remember to install packages. npm i (or similar if you're using another package manager). Additionally, you may need to build depending on where symbols are being loaded from.

The provided checklist is irrelevant. It refers to actual errors, not to VSCode incorrectly identifying errors despite working compilation.

same problem here, I'm using the latest visual studio code (1.95.3) and it keeps showing errors on every primeng component I'm using.
